# regex for a whole word containing dots within a sentence

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regular expression to catch a whole word or expression within a sentence that contains dots:

```
this is an example test.abc.123 for what I am looking for
```

In this case i want to catch "test.abc.123"

I tried with this regex:

```
(.*)(\b.+\..++\b)(.*)
```

- `(.*)` some signs or not
- `(\b.+\..++\b)` a word containing some signs followed by at least on dot that is followed by some signs and this at least once
- `(.*)` some more signs nor not#

but it gets me: "abc.123 for what I am looking for"

I see that I got something completely wrong, can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: You probably need `\w+(?:\.+\w+)+`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this pattern: `(?=\w+\.{1,})[^ ]+`.

Details: `(?=\w+\.{1,})` - positive lookahead to locate starting of a word with at least one dot (`.`). Then, start matching from that position, until space with this pattern `[^ ]+`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CeJJXs/1)

Comment: thanks a lot, @revo in this case I accept it as a word

Comment: @Jefeinfiltrado Then we should call it a sub-string and you shouldn't use word boundaries `\b`. The easiest way to match such sub-strings would be `\S+\.\S*`.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to match part of a string you don't need to match entire string (unless you are restricted by a functionality).

Your regex is so greedy. It also has dots every where (`.+` is not a good choice most of the time). It doesn't have a precise point to start and finish either. You only need:

```
\w+(?:\.+\w+)+
```

It looks for strings that begin and end with word characters and contain at least a period. See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/WIjhLU/1)

Answer (score 0):

This regex pattern matches strings with two or more dots:

```
.*\..*\..*
```

"."  matches any character except line-breaks
"*"  repeats previous tokens 0 or more times
"." matches a single dot, slash is used for escape

.* Match any character and continue matching until next token

**test.abc.123**

(.) Match a single dot

**test.** abc.123

.* Again, any character and continue matching until next token

**test.example**.com

. Matches a single dot

**test.example.** com

.* Matches any character and continue matching until next token

**test.example.com**